# Maven-publish logic inside Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, maven, gradle, kotlin

I've got a few libraries that I want to publish to a local Maven. I want to use a Plugin for this to maximum reuse.

The basic code setup is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'LibraryPlugin'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0q"
    }
}

def groupId = "x.y.z"
def artifactId = "LibZ"

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            parseDebugLibraryResources(MavenPublication) {
                setGroupId groupId
                setArtifactId artifactId
                version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After a `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal` it is correctly placed there.
I want to move that project.afterEvaluate > publishing > publications stuff into the Plugin so I can reuse it in multiple projects.

Here's the Plugin code:

```
class LibraryPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.plugins.apply("kotlin-android")
        project.plugins.apply("maven-publish")
        project.dependencies.add("implementation", BuildPlugins.kotlinStandardLibrary)
        val extension = project.extensions.getByType<LibraryExtension>()
        extension.configureLibrary()

        project.afterEvaluate {
         //   publishing {

         //   }
        }
    }

    private fun LibraryExtension.configureLibrary() {
        setCompileSdkVersion(AndroidSdk.compile)
        defaultConfig.apply {
            setMinSdkVersion(AndroidSdk.min)
            setTargetSdkVersion(AndroidSdk.target)
            testInstrumentationRunner = TestLibraries.UI.instrumentationRunner
        }
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't know the "publishing" node in Project.afterEvaluate. How can I move that code in to the Plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to get the publishing node like this:

```
val publishing = project.properties["publishing"] as PublishingExtension
```

Full example:

```
class LibraryPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.plugins.apply("kotlin-android")
        project.plugins.apply("maven-publish")
        project.dependencies.add("implementation", BuildPlugins.kotlinStandardLibrary)
        val extension = project.extensions.getByType<LibraryExtension>()
        extension.configureLibrary()


        project.afterEvaluate {
            val publishing = project.properties["publishing"] as PublishingExtension
            publishing {

            }
        }
    }

    private fun LibraryExtension.configureLibrary() {
        setCompileSdkVersion(AndroidSdk.compile)
        defaultConfig.apply {
            setMinSdkVersion(AndroidSdk.min)
            setTargetSdkVersion(AndroidSdk.target)
            testInstrumentationRunner = TestLibraries.UI.instrumentationRunner
        }
    }
}
```